# How to use HealthKit in WidgetKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, healthkit, widgetkit

I'm trying to load step data in my widget example here, however, I can only print the steps and not display the steps in the widget itself.

As you can see here, I'm printing the `steps` and then I'm assigning it to a variable, but that variable `currentSteps` stays `0` when I run the widget.

```swift
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

// ...

struct widgetextensionEntryView : View {
    @State private var currentSteps: Int = 0
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    let data = DataService()
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Time:")
            Text(entry.date.formatted(.dateTime.hour().minute().second()))
            
            Text("Current:")
            Text(String(currentSteps))
                .onAppear {
                    fetchDaySteps(date: Date(), completion: { s in
                        print(s)
                        self.currentSteps = s
                        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
                        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "widgetextension")
                    })
                    
                }
            
            Text("Step Goal:")
            Text(String(data.progress()))
        }
    }
}

extension Date {
    func startOfDay() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
    
    var endOfDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, of: self)!
    }
}

func fetchDaySteps(date: Date, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
    let startOfDay = date.startOfDay()
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
        withStart: startOfDay,
        end: date.endOfDay,
        options: .strictStartDate
    )
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(
        quantityType: stepsQuantityType,
        quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
        options: .cumulativeSum
    ) { _, result, _ in
        guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(Int(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()).rounded()))
        }
    }
    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
}
```

It's weird that the printing works, but it doesn't show the steps in the `Text` widget.

Comment: You have to feed the data in `getTimeline` widgets are like a GIF things like `@State` don't work make all the variables a `let`